# Can I disable product reviews in Google Structured Search?

Tags: seo, microdata, structured-data, user-reviews

I am getting annoying warning messages from Google Structured Search about not supplying product reviews under offers. We don't have product reviews as it doesn't fit our target customer base. Is there a way of disabling it?  If there isn't, does it negatively effect our search visibility?

Comment: With "Google Structured Search", do you mean the Search Console or the Structured Data Testing Tool? And to keep the question for the future, can you please include the warning in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's only a warning. Ignore it if you have no reviews. It has no effect on search visibility beyond you can't get review stars without reviews.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It us already scary how Google tyrannizes online commerce and content through its search monopoly. To add insult to injury, they arbitrarily flag "warnings" based their own overly generalized ideas on what information is important to businesses and customers. While not an error per se, flagging a warning for not including reviews (as opposed to other microdata) clearly shows what bits of data is most important to them. In this case, they value highly gamable, crowd generated data.